# map with lambda vs map with function - how to pass more than one variable to function?

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, map-function

I wanted to learn about using `map` in python and a google search brought me to http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_fncs_map_filter_reduce.php which I have found helpful.

One of the codes on that page uses a for loop and puts `map` within that for loop in an interesting way, and the list used within the `map` function actually takes a list of 2 functions. Here is the code:

```
def square(x): 
    return (x**2)

def cube(x):
    return (x**3)

funcs = [square, cube]

for r in range(5):
    value = map(lambda x: x(r), funcs)
    print value
```

output:

```
[0, 0]
[1, 1]
[4, 8]
[9, 27]
[16, 64]
```

So, at this point in that tutorial, I thought "well if you can write that code with a function on the fly (lambda), then it could be written using a standard function using `def`". So I changed the code to this:

```
def square(x): 
    return (x**2)

def cube(x):
    return (x**3)

def test(x):
    return x(r)

funcs = [square, cube]

for r in range(5):
    value = map(test, funcs)
    print value
```

I got the same output as the first piece of code, but it bothered me that variable `r` was taken from the global namespace and that the code is not tight functional programming. And there is where I got tripped up. Here is my code:

```
def square(x): 
    return (x**2)

def cube(x):
    return (x**3)

def power(x):
    return x(r)

def main():
    funcs = [square, cube]
    for r in range(5):
        value = map(power, funcs)
        print value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have played around with this code, but the issue is with passing into the function `def power(x)`. I have tried numerous ways of trying to pass into this function, but lambda has the ability to automatically assign `x` variable to each iteration of the list `funcs`.

**Is there a way to do this by using a standard `def` function, or is it not possible and only lambda can be used?** Since I am learning python and this is my first language, I am trying to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could nest the `power()` function in the `main()` function:

```
def main():
    def power(x):
        return x(r)

    funcs = [square, cube]
    for r in range(5):
        value = map(power, funcs)
        print value
```

so that `r` is now taken from the surrounding scope again, but is not a global. Instead it is a *closure* variable instead.

However, using a `lambda` is just another way to inject `r` from the surrounding scope here and passing it into the `power()` function:

```
def power(r, x):
    return x(r)

def main():
    funcs = [square, cube]
    for r in range(5):
        value = map(lambda x: power(r, x), funcs)
        print value
```

Here `r` is still a non-local, taken from the parent scope!

You could create the lambda with `r` being a default value for a second argument:

```
def power(r, x):
    return x(r)

def main():
    funcs = [square, cube]
    for r in range(5):
        value = map(lambda x, r=r: power(r, x), funcs)
        print value
```

Now `r` is passed in as a default value instead, so it was taken as a local. But for the purposes of your `map()` that doesn't actually make a difference here.

Answer (score 3):

Currying is another option. Because a function of two arguments is the same as a function of one argument that returns another function that takes the remaining argument, you can write it like this:

```
def square(x):
    return (x**2)

def cube(x):
    return (x**3)

def power(r):
    return lambda(x): x(r) # This is where we construct our curried function

def main():
    funcs = [square, cube]
    for y in range(5):
        value = map(power(y), funcs) # Here, we apply the first function
                                     # to get at the second function (which
                                     # was constructed with the lambda above).
        print value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To make the relation a little more explicit, a function of the type `(a, b) -> c` (a function that takes an argument of type `a` and an argument of type `b` and returns a value of type `c`) is equivalent to a function of type `a -> (b -> c)`.

### Extra stuff about the equivalence

If you want to get a little deeper into the math behind this equivalence, you can see this relationship using a bit of algebra. Viewing these types as algebraic data types, we can translate any function `a -> b` to b<sup>a</sup> and any pair `(a, b)` to a * b. Sometimes function types are called "exponentials" and pair types are called "product types" because of this connection. From here, we can see that

c<sup>(a * b)</sup>  =  (c<sup>b</sup>)<sup>a</sup>

and so,

```
(a, b) -> c  ~=  a -> (b -> c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply pass the functions as part of the argument to `power()`, and use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to create the required `(value, func)` combinations?

```
from itertools import product

# ...

def power((value, func)):
    return func(value)

for r in range(5):
    values = map(power, product([r], funcs))
    print values
```

Or if you don't want / require the results to be grouped by functions, and instead want a flat list, you could simply do:

```
values = map(power, product(range(5), funcs))
print values
```

---

Note: The signature `power((value, func))` defines `power()` to accept a single 2-tuple argument that is automatically unpacked into `value` and `func`.

It's equivalent to

```
def power(arg):
    value, func = arg
```